# Padding a matrix without using loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix like this:

```
A = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to pad it such a way i get this result:

```
result = array([[1., 1., 2., 3., 3.],
                [4., 4., 5., 6., 6.],
                [7., 7., 8., 9., 9.]])
```

without using a loop.
A sample of my code that uses a loop looks this way:

```
B = np.array(np.zeros(shape=(3,5)))
for i in range(0,3):
    B[i] = np.pad(A[i],(1,1),'constant',constant_values=(A[i][0], A[i][-1]))
```

Now I want an optimized way of doing it without using a loop to do it.

Thanks

Comment: use `np.repeat`

Comment: uhmm i don't that will work. from the documentation, it repeats itself in array. Just tried it.

Answer (score 5):

Try `np.pad` with `mode="edge"`:

```py
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

B = np.pad(A, ((0, 0), (1, 1)), mode="edge")
print(B)
```

Prints:

```
[[1 1 2 3 3]
 [4 4 5 6 6]
 [7 7 8 9 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `repeat` across columns:

```
In [215]: np.repeat(A,(2,1,2),axis=1)
Out[215]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 9, 9]])
```

If `A` has more columns that you don't want to repeat you could construct a extended `(2,1,1,1,2)`.

`repeat` tends to be relatively fast, so I'm guessing it would be faster than the more complicated `pad`.

Another way

```
In [216]: np.hstack((A[:,[0]],A,A[:,[-1]]))
Out[216]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 9, 9]])
```